# Save an xls file with FileInputStream : A file is in a different file format than its extension indicates

Tags: java, excel, file

I'm trying to save an xls file, it work fine but when I open the file I've got that error "A file is in a different file format than its extension indicates".
It seems that the file is corrupted. 
Here's my code:

```
        File ff= new File("c.xls");
        FileInputStream inn = new FileInputStream(ff);
        OutputStream stt=new FileOutputStream("d.xls");
        stt.write(inn.read());
        stt.close();
```

Comment: Is it an Excel 2007+ file?

Comment: Yes it is a 2007 file !

Comment: the excel extension for 2007 is .xlsx

Comment: I don't think that's my issue here! even with .xlsx it doesn't work !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
stt.write(inn.read());
```

is only reading one byte. You need to loop over the input file, writing out what you read.

Comment: And how to do that! I tried that code but it doesn't work 
            `FileInputStream inn = new FileInputStream(ff);
            OutputStream stt=new FileOutputStream("b.txt");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; // Adjust if you want
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = inn.read(buffer)) != -1)
            {
             stt.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            };`

Comment: That looks ok on the first view. What do you mean by "doe't work"? Do you get error messages? DOes the output file have a wrong file size?

Comment: Finally I could open it without errors, with the same code I posted in the last comment I don't know why it doesn't work at the first time. Thank you so much !